# Download files in bulk, but confirm each download

Tags: download, wget

I wish to download all pictures from an album. The album is an HTML page hosted on the Internet, which has both links to some other stuff in the site and thumbnails, which link to the image viewing page. The filenames are not sequential.
I coulnd't find a solution to this problem so far, apart from wgetting the album with level 2 recursion and filtering file types, and then manually selecting the desired pictures. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: So you want to scrape an album of images that hosts some and links to others? And you don't want thumbnails which may or may not be hosted internally or externally?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what OS you have access to, but I meant to expand on this simple OS X `Automator` demo script, which was added to our "bag o' tricks" some time back - It's so simple, I'd have embarked on putting together a Perl script utilizing `wget` as you suggested a long time before thinking using this would work.  Here is the script in `Automator` *flow view* - even if you don't have access to `Automator`, you could use this *workflow* to perhaps implement the script in, say, `Perl` and `wget`:

[image]

Comment: I currently don't have access to a Mac, but the algorithm seems to be wrong for the task - notice the album links to image viewers, i.e. pages that show the image together with useless crap. Also, it uses thumbnails.